# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, alembic

got a problem developing app using alembic

1) Here's my project structure

[image]

2) Backend package structure

[image]

3) Alembic folder structure

[image]

Well, at the env.py i have imports

```
from backend.db.db_manager import declarative_base
from backend.db_config import url
```

When I try to execute `alembic revision --autogenerate` command from ROOT folder it fails with "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend'"

Comment: Put an `__init__.py` file in that folder. Also in your `db` and `alembic` folders.

Comment: @erip created __init__.py in alembic, db, backend, root folders. not working